# Eclipse doesn't move classes compiled with maven to tomcat running directory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Well I'm running Eclipse with Tomcat runtime environment (it is run from Eclipse) and I've recently turned my web project to Maven project. Now it finally compiles well, however when I try running it on server it doesn't seem to load the compiled classes and hibernate configuration files to the Tomcat working directory in :

```
**D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myProject**
```

So I have to copy all the compiled classes and practically all the missing files manually everytime I now change anything...

Can I change anything in Eclipse settings? Also where should I output my compiled classes from Maven? At the moment the build in pom.xml looks like this:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <directory>${basedir}/build</directory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using a Maven plugin (e.g., m2eclipse) I thought it would do this automagically.

Comment: @DaveNewton  I am using it, but somehow it doesn't. Do you know maybe how it needs to be set up to do that?

Comment: Seems to be working now, though I still don't understand the reason why it now works, I went to the Maven settings in Eclipse, changed nothing, then chose to clean up the Tomcat server and then it started working. Funny is that I had cleaned Tomcat server tons of times and it never helped. So I have no Idea what changed...